# Tensorflow: set column of tensor to infinity

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, matrix

Let's say I have a tensor

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(arr)
```

in numpy, I could do:
`arr[:,[0,2]] = -np.inf`, but since "TF doesn't support item assignment", I'm not sure whether there is a way to do this in TF 2.3?

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to do that:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Input data
# Tensor must be float type to hold infinity
tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], dtype=tf.float32)
inf_cols = [0, 2]
# Make mask of replaced columns
col_mask = tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(inf_cols, 1),
                         tf.ones_like(inf_cols, dtype=tf.bool),
                         [tf.shape(tensor)[1]])
# Replace columns
res = tf.where(tf.expand_dims(col_mask, 0), -np.inf, tensor)
tf.print(res)
# [[-inf 2 -inf]
#  [-inf 5 -inf]
#  [-inf 8 -inf]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible way:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(arr)
mask = tf.constant(list(range(2))) != 1
tf.where(mask, tensor, tf.constant(-np.inf))
```